# EC2 Linux MongoDB crash without logs - trap?

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

For a few days - maybe a week - mongodb is randomly crashing without any meaningful log in mongodb.log. It just works, then stops responding.

The last lines in the file look purely  functional:

```
2016-05-31T20:41:59.273+0000 I COMMAND  [conn146] query prod.user query: { username: "anonymousUser" } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:328 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:21 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 44 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 22 } } } 7049ms
2016-05-31T20:42:00.665+0000 I COMMAND  [conn124] command admin.$cmd command: buildInfo { buildinfo: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:813 locks:{} 400ms
2016-05-31T20:42:01.694+0000 I COMMAND  [conn150] query prod.announcements planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3 nreturned:1 reslen:433 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 4 } } } 2470ms
```

I don't have kernel logging - just activated it.

I /var/log/messages I have this line at 20:42:04, ie 3 seconds after the last mongo query is logged

```
May 31 20:42:04 ip-172-31-6-27 kernel: [213213.126793] traps: mongod[9632] trap int3 ip:1263bc5 sp:7fb5247a4250 error:0
```

From what I've read, traps are a sort of interrupt, but couldn't really understand what that would mean. Did the system just told mongo to stop? Is there any way to understand what happened?

Edit: forgot to add some info about my conf:

- mongod version is 3.0.12
- OS info:

  ```
  NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
  VERSION="2015.03"
  ID="amzn"
  ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
  VERSION_ID="2015.03"
  PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03"
  ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
  CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.03:ga"
  HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
  Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.03
  ```
- db size is around 60 Mo

Edit 2: ran db.serverStatus() (it was after I rebooted the instance, not sure it is of any real help debugging the issue) and saved results [here](http://pastebin.com/XKzKDe41)

Edit 3: trying to see any memory issue in dmesg

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-27 log]$ cat dmesg | grep memory
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000098000] 98000 size 24576
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x3fe00000-0x3fffffff]
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x3c000000-0x3fdfffff]
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00100000-0x3bffffff]
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.028161] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.627295] Freeing initrd memory: 13968K (ffff88003724c000 - ffff880037ff0000)
[    1.584023] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1088K (ffffffff81ad4000 - ffffffff81be4000)
[    1.591756] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1416K (ffff88000149e000 - ffff880001600000)
[    1.598026] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1928K (ffff88000181e000 - ffff880001a00000)
```

Thanks for any help you could give here :)

Comment: Are you out of disk space?

Comment: Check /var/log/kern.log or dmesg for "out of memory" messages.  Sounds like the Linux OOM killer.

Comment: @ReubenL. running `df -T` indicates only 17% disk use, so I guess I'm ok

Comment: @KarenB I don't have a kern.log yet, I've activated kern logs since the last issue to try and find more info. Added info about what dmesg contains on memory in the main post because of formatting

Comment: If that's all there is in dmesg about memory, then the OOM killer is probably off the hook for this one.  This mongodb bug report may help, though: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20103

Comment: Issue just reoccured, and the mongodb logs clearly indicate an OOM. At least now I can look for how to solve it :)